# Having a bit of trouble with min/max distance from sphere to point

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The sphere is

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 81$

and the point is $(5,6,9)$

I am using Langrane multipliers , but the answers I am getting are so far off. I will post my system of equations soon.

I found the gradient of $F: (2(x-5), 2 (y-6), 2(z-9))$
Gradient of $G: (2x, 2y, 2z)$

$2x-10 = 2 \lambda x$
$2y-12 = 2 \lambda y$
$2z-18 = 2 \lambda z$
$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 81$

This system seems very challenging to solve.

Comment: It's not so bad, actually: you can express your coordinates in terms of $\lambda$, then plug these into your last equation. From there, the solution follows quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you draw the line through the center of the sphere (which is the origin) and $(5,6,9)$ it intersects the sphere in two points.  One of these is the min distance, the other is the max distance.  It doesn't even matter if the point is inside or outside the sphere.  So find the distance from the origin to $(5,6,9)$ and add/subtract the radius of the sphere.  If you draw the corresponding 2D figure you can see what is happening.

Comment: And where exactly can you draw it? Because the answer using Langrane leads to answers like x= +/- 45/sqrt(142)

Comment: @Ross: What you say is, of course, true. But I think the OP would rather get a better feel for Lagrange multipliers than know the answer to this particular problem.

Comment: Just make the circle $x^2+y^2=81$ and the point $(7,12)$ for example.  Draw the line through the origin and the point.  Is it required to use Lagrange multipliers, or do you specifically want to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The system of equations is rather easy to solve. The first three equations give:

$$x = \frac{5}{1-\lambda}$$
$$y = \frac{6}{1-\lambda}$$
$$z = \frac{9}{1-\lambda}$$

Now just plug these values into the fourth equation to get $\lambda$. (But first you have to decide whether $x^2+y^2+z^2$ equals $81$ or $18$ $-$ I expect that $18$ is the typo.)

Comment: It was equal to 81. I solved for Lambda and got 61/81.

Comment: Well then you must go back and edit your question! (Just click on "edit".)

Comment: ok I did. So now that Lambda is 61/81 would that mean the minimum is -61/81 and max 61/81? Once I have lambda, how do I solve for those values?

Comment: No, you have been careless. You want to solve $\frac{142}{81} = (1-\lambda)^2$, right? Now try again. The answers are not simple fractions, nor is one the negative of the other.

Comment: Ok. I see where I went wrong when solving for lambda.
Now I am finding the minimum to be -45/sqrt(142), -27 times sqrt(2/71), -81/sqrt (142).

Comment: You have two values for $\lambda$, right? Now which one gives the minimum distance, and which one gives the maximum? (And I must say your decision to write $-54\sqrt{1/142}$ as $-27\sqrt{2/71}$ looks rather odd here!)

Comment: Yea I understand. Ill just plug that in the original equation and see what happens. For the minimum I am finding Zero.

Comment: Does Zero seem right?

Comment: I give up.${}{}$